# Select all occurrences of current selection

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio code there is a command `editor.action.selectHighlights` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. It will select all occurrences of current selection.

Is this also possible in Visual Studio Community 2017?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Ctrl+Shift+Alt+,
```

> Keyboard setting: Edit.InsertCaretsatAllMatching

Also a second way to avoid remembering a shortcut can be found via VS2017 menu.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's it. Thank you! Time to rebind this tho.. three modifier keys (Ctrl+Shift+Alt).. that's ridiculous.

Comment: @spassvogel This is why Keyboard setting: Edit.InsertCaretsatAllMatching was provided! 
By the way the default shortcut does not work for me for reason unknown.
I also use only the next reference as i have more control and if i want all i just keep it pressed.

Answer (score 1):

It's `SHIF + ALT + Ç` for Visual Studio 2022.

Please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: it's `Shift + Alt + ;` on English layout keyboard